# Login to PC using NFC-enabled Phone

Tags: windows-10, android, nfc

I have a Windows PC with an NFC reader and an Android device with NFC capabilities. Is there any way I can unlock my PC using NFC enabled Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no ways to login to your computer using NFC.
There is a project that you can find in YouTube where a guy managed to connect an Arduino to a BadUSB pen to run scripts that automatically input keystrokes to auto login Windows after a fingerprint reader detect a authorized fingerprint.
And you can Wake On LAN your computer using an NFC tag, but not the login part.

Comment: Is this a restriction due to NFC or Windows, or a combination of the two. I have seen people login to their PC with smart cards, so maybe some kind of Smart Card emulation on the Android side might work?